# Instalação Cartopy

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tô tentando instalar a biblioteca cartopy. Porém não tô conseguindo. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Tentei pelo pypi e retornou o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\Rafa>pip install cartopy

Collecting cartopy
  Using cached Cartopy-0.15.1.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\rafa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

Tentei também pelo anaconda também e retorna que só pode ser instalada com a versão 3.6 do python, porém eu tô com a versão 3.6 e a 3.6.3 já instalada

```
(C:\Users\Rafa\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Rafa\Documents>conda install -c scitools cartopy
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - cartopy -> numpy 1.8* -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Rafael, por que apagou a pergunta? Estava respondendo com algumas orientações a respeito do seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completando a resposta do @Vegas, segundo a [documentação ( Em Inglês )](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html) o jeito mais fácil de instalar o *Cartopy* em todas as *Plataformas* é utilizando o *Conda*, com o seguinte comando.

```
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

Você pode também fazer a instalação a partir do código-fonte disponível no [Github](https://github.com/SciTools/Cartopy), após clonar o repositório, execute o comando no *Terminal*, *Power Shell*, etc..:

```
python setup.py install
```

O *Cartopy* requisita do pacote *python-numpy* caso esteja utilizando distribuições *Linux*, pode instalar a partir do comando:

```
apt-get install python-numpy
```

Talvez seja necessário instalar o pacote de *Desenvolvimento*, para isso utilize o comando:

```
apt-get install python-numpy-dev
```

Comment: Eu usei esse comando. Ele instalar normalmente, porém o cartopy não aparece na pasta site-packges do python. Quando tento importar o módulo cartopy vem o avisso de que não existe modulo chamado cartopy

Comment: >>> import cartopy as ct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy'

Comment: Você só tem uma versão do *Python* instalada ?

Comment: a 3.6.3. Me parece que a cartopy só tá funcionando na 3.4. Vou testar ele. Dúvida: ao instalar o novo python, vou ter que instalar novamente os pacotes?

Comment: Sim, sempre quando a versões diferentes até aonde eu sei tem que instalar

Answer (score 1):

Tente usando:

> conda install -c conda-forge cartopy=0.15.1